# Safeargs generated directions do not work (Android)

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have such settings in the project:

*apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'*

*ext.navigationVersion = "1.0.0-beta02"*

*classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"*

*implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"*
*implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"*

nav_graph.xml:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.terkacleaning.ui.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">

        <action 
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</fragment>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.terkacleaning.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"/>
```

Methods are generated:

```
    LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeFragment()
```

But these methods don't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [Safe Args documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args), constructing a `NavDirections` object isn't enough - you need to pass it to `navController.navigate()`:

```
navController.navigate(
    LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeFragment())
```